# Is it possible to configure a WCF Rest Service in SharePoint?

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to make a WCF Rest service inside SharePoint. I'm using webHttpBinding as the binding and "WebGet" attributes on my service methods. I deployed in a standard web application and it worked very well. Then, I deployed to SharePoint (ISAPI folder) and didn't work. I googled about it and the unique solution I found is to make my WCF folder anonymous. Doing this the service worked fine but I need to get the user that is accesing my service.

So, is there any way to configure a WCF service using webHttpBinding as binding using authentication?

My web.config file is this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="Behaviour1" name="PoC.WCF.MockData">
            <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="PoC.WCF.IMockData"></endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Behaviour1">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RestBehaviour">
                 <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The service contract interface is this:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace PoC.WCF
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMockData
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
        string DoWork();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{message}")]
        string GetMessage(string message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get it after few days of googling and testing. The solution is very easy and you don't have to do anything in your development excepting use a factory on your service. This link explain what factory use depending on the service type: [*WCF Services in SharePoint Foundation 2010*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521586.aspx)

So, the solution to my problem is to modify the "*svc*" file and add the factory you need. In my case, for a Rest service, I have to use "*MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory*". This is my code:

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Service="PoC.WCF.MockData, PoC.WCF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a1a45d52b868570"
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```