# How to create a Rest wcf service on SharePoint?

Tags: rest, iis, wcf, web-config

I'm trying to make a WCF Rest service inside SharePoint. 
but it doesn't work and I get **404** :(

I set the svc file like that

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
Service="MyNamespace.myservice, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" 
Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

and the web.config like that:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehaviour" name="MyNamespace.myservice">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="namespace.ImyService"></endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyBehaviour">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RestBehaviour">
                 <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

the code like that:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface Imyservice
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Work")]
        string Work();
    }

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    class myservice : Imyservice
    {
        public string Work()
        {
          return ("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```

And nothing. When I'm trying to browse the service(.svc) or one of the methods, I get 404..

I should mention, I already managed to provide a Soap service at this same server.

please help me.

Comment: If I understood what you mean by "browse", I think that is just normal behavior. Try to actually call your method and see if it works as expected.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I tried to call the method -> ...localhost/_vti_bin/Myservice.svc/Work, and it didn't work...

Comment: Strange... your sample is very close to [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22890/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-wcf-rest-service-in-sharepoint).  I am doing the same (specifying 'MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory' in the .svc file and WebGet on the service interface - no web.config manual modification needed) and I am able to consume my service both with JQuery $.ajax and Angularjs $http. Have you checked all the files have been correctly deployed to the ISAPI folder?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist you are right. I figured it out. I eventually checks the eventViewer and saw exceptions like "...more than one endpoints cofigured..." or something like that. I fixed that, and now it works :)

Comment: actually... I think that you should be able to just use the factory with no "custom web.config" in the first place, but glad you have it figured out ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. After checking the *EventViewer* (which is recommended)  I found some exceptions related to my custom service service similar to "...more than one endpoints configured...". I therefore fixed my configuration by adding this:

```
<webHttpBinding>
<binding name="RestBinding">
    <security mode="None" />
    </security>
</binding>
</webHttpBinding >
```